How can I get a pointer to a managed function to provide to unmanaged code as a callback?
I am interested in displaying a really-old-style open file dialog (that is, one that does not act like Windows file explorer) in a C# application. I found this example for calling the legacy GetOpenFileName function via [DllImport] and extern. However, to actually get the non-Explorer behavior, the GOFN page indicates I also need to set a hook:

Windows continues to support the old-style Open dialog box for applications that want to maintain a user-interface consistent with the old-style user-interface. To display the old-style Open dialog box, enable an OFNHookProcOldStyle hook procedure and ensure that the OFN_EXPLORER flag is not set.

I modified the example and created the function below to be a OFNHookProcOldStyle callback, which, if I'm reading the documentation for such callbacks correctly, should not change any behavior by simply always returning 0 (process the message). Having such a hook set should disable the Explorer behavior in the absence of the OFN_EXPLORER flag to re-enable it.
public static UIntPtr SimpleOfnHookProcOldStyle(
    [In] IntPtr hdlg, [In] uint uimsg, [In] UIntPtr wParam, [In] IntPtr lParam)
{
    return UIntPtr.Zero;
}

I set the OFN_ENABLEHOOK flag like so:
int OFN_ENABLEHOOK = (int)new Int32Converter().ConvertFromString("0x00000020");
ofn.flags = OFN_ENABLEHOOK;

However, I also need to set the actual hook callback, which is an IntPtr. How can I get an IntPtr to my SimpleOfnHookProcOldStyle method so that I can set it as the hook?

have you looked thew new interop improvements in .NET5+, it has samples that might be of use, i.e. A basic usage scenario of passing a managed callback to a native function would, without UnmanagedCallersOnlyAttribute, look like...

Why not just have const int OFN_ENABLEHOOK = 0x00000020  ?

@Dai I didn't know int supported direct assignment of hex values like that, thanks!

You need to

Define a static delegate with the same signature and assign your static function to it.

public delegate UIntPtr Delegate_type(IntPtr hdlg, uint uimsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
public static Delegate_type native_callback = SimpleOfnHookProcOldStyle;


Use GCHandle.Alloc to prevent the garbage collector from deleting it.

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(native_callback);


Use Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate to get an IntPtr to this static delegate.

IntPtr funcPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(native_callback);


Call handle.Free() after the dialog is closed so you don't leak memory.


Good to know I don't need the Pinned.  I wasn't using it in my C++/CLI version of this and this answer was making me begin to question whether or not that was an accident waiting to happen.

info on why you don't need to pin the delegate https://stackoverflow.com/a/19866119/15649230
